# Can anyone share working hangout chat api example with php?

Tags: google-hangouts

I am looking for Google chat api code with service account. I tried following code but getting some errors, not sure what I am missing.

include_once BP."/lib/google-api/vendor/autoload.php";

```
$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(BP."/scripts/hangout/mytee-products-e6e5368c4246.json");
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot']);

try{
        $service = new Google_Service_HangoutsChat( $client );
        print_r($service->spaces->listSpaces());
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        print $e->getMessage();
    }
```

{ "error": { "code": 404, "message": "Requested entity was not found.", "errors": [ { "message": "Requested entity was not found.", "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound" } ], "status": "NOT_FOUND" } }

Answer (score 1):

### Consideration

**Note**: A recent [commit](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/commit/2ab61398fa6c7e319f3665fbf0c01df6f1f683ec) to the google-api-php-client Github repository updated class names with namespace notation.

You are using namespace notation (`Google\Client()`) while not activating it beforehand. You should adopt a different notation if you don't intend to use namespaces.

### Solution

Please refer to this syntax to use `Google_Client` PHP Class methods in your PHP script:

```php
include_once __DIR__ . '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__."/path/to/credentials.json");
$client->setApplicationName("Your_Application_Name");
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot']);

try {
        $service = new Google_Service_HangoutsChat( $client );
        print_r($service->spaces->listSpaces());
} catch(Exception $e) {
        print $e->getMessage();
}
```

### References

[PHP Namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

[Google PHP API Service Account](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php)

Comment: Sorry but it is not making any difference. Still not working and showing same error.

Comment: It works on my side, what is the line of your code that produces the 404 error?

Comment: showing exception { "error": { "code": 404, "message": "Requested entity was not found.", "errors": [ { "message": "Requested entity was not found.", "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound" } ], "status": "NOT_FOUND" } }

May be i am missing settings ?

Comment: Yes, what's the line that returns this exception?

Comment: i got the solution by google team, i was missing bot configuration at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/chat.googleapis.com/hangouts-chat?project={your-project}&pli=1&authuser=1